# Do I need to code the success function of the ajax call to completes the posting of the data to the view?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m making an ajax call using the datapicker.  The controller is called and I confirmed that the data is sent to the view by using breakpoints.  To me this seems be a success.  However, nothing shows in the view even though I confirmed that the model that’s sent to the view has data.

As I’m new to using ajax I’m not sure what to do with the success function of the call.  Should I be putting something in the success function of the ajax call that completes the posting of the data to the view?  Can someone help me with writing the success portion of my code?  I’ve looked at samples but they all seem to be using success differently so I don't quite know how it would work with my scenario.  Here’s my view and the script:

```
 <div class ="ui-widget" >
 <label for ="datep">Date: </label><input id="datep" />
 </div>


 @if (Model.Assignments != null)
 {

 <table>
<tr>
   <th>
      Assignment  Course
    </th>



    <th>
        Class Day
    </th>


    <th>
     Class Time
    </th>


 </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Assignments.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
 {

if (item.Data.Date.ToShortDateString() == ViewBag.theDate)
{
<tr>
<td>

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Course)

</td>


    <td>





         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.HomeworkGrade)

     </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Date)
      </td>




        </tr>
     }
 }

    </table>

 }



   <input type="hidden" autofocus=true/>




 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datep").datepicker({ showOn: "both", buttonText: "Select Date", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-2:+2", showOtherMonths: true, onSelect: function (date, datepickder) {
        var sltdDate = { selectedDate: date };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Schedule/GetSchedule",
            data: sltdDate,
            async: false,
            datatype: "html",
            sucess: function (data) {
            }
        });

    }




    });

   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are requesting information to the server (as is your case) you need to do something in the success function.

What to do? It depends.

The usual thing is placing the returned data inside a container.

So, if your controller action returned just data... you should create the HTML (iterating over the returned data for example) in the success function... and then place that in another container div.

Sometimes... you just need to update a text, so it is easier... but you need to do something for that.

If you use the Microsoft Ajax helpers in MVC... they receive a parameter where you say which dom element will be the container that need to be replaced with the return of the Ajax call.

Here you can see the entire reference of jQuery Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**At the end you have ver simple examples.**
Note that the examples are written a little different as you did... it is the newer form of writting the call: now instead of using the `success` function... you append a `.done(function{ /// })` to handle once the request is finished.

So... check the examples and what you find in the Done function, it is the same you could place in your success function.

Comment: So I created a div with id returnedData and put this lone in my success function...$("#returnedData"); but nothing gets placed in the container after the call.  I tried placing an alert in the function also and it also did not fire. Found this mean that the call was not a success?

Comment: Actually I just noticed a typo in my success.  Now it works!  Thanks.